# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.widget.LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

```
 MainLayout=(LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.LinLaySub);
        for(int k=0;k<Dist_cat.length;k++) {
            Cursor c = db.getQueryResult("select * from prod_mas where sub_name='" + Dist_catname[k] + "'");   
           for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                ChildLayout=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                ChildLayout.setWeightSum(100);
                ChildLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                ChildLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sublay));
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                ChildLayout.setId(i);
                edit_phy = new EditText(getActivity());
                edit_phyAll.add(edit_phy);
                edit_phy.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
                edit_phy.setId(+i + 1);
                edit_phy.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ChildLayout.addView(edit_phy);

                edit_trn = new EditText(getActivity());
                edit_trnAll.add(edit_trn);
                edit_trn.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
                edit_trn.setId(+i + 2);
                edit_trn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ChildLayout.addView(edit_trn);

                MainLayout.onViewAdded(ChildLayout);
                c.moveToNext();
            }

        }
```

I am trying to add some ui-element programatically,but i am getting error i.e,

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onViewAdded:

can anyone help me to solve.

Comment: Why do you want to call `onViewAdded()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change line**

```
MainLayout.onViewAdded(ChildLayout);
```

**to**

```
MainLayout.addView(ChildLayout);
```